# Attributes for .setAttribute method

Tags: javascript, attributes

I'm new to javaScript and I'm watching a lynda dot com video on JavaScript Essentials by Simon Allardice. In lesson 22, he goes over how to change DOM elements using JS. In an example, he uses .setAttribute(“**align**”, “**right**”); to change the alignment of some paragraph text to align right witin a div tag.

Does anyone know where I can find a reference list of available attributes to use for other DOM elements? I tried to search "javascript attributes reference list", but it returns html attributes.

Comment: They're not part of Javascript, they're just the attributes that are allowed in HTML.

Comment: Like `<a>` can have an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML element and DOM element are synonymous. In the example you are using javascript to set HTML (DOM) element attributes. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) is a good resource.